# Assigning user a site_id on creating a new site in controller.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So far I have `user belongs_to :sites` and `site has_many :users`. And i have `user_id` in the sites schema and `site_id` in the users schema.

I'm trying to set it up where once a user creates a new site, than that site_id is assigned to that user. And only one site can be created per user.

I've tried `@user.site_id = Site.find(params[:id])` in the sites_controller.rb, but no luck.

sites_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @site = Site.new(site_params)
    @site.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @site.save
        format.html { redirect_to @site, notice: 'Site was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @site }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        message = find_message(:signed_up)
        flash[:notice] = message
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        if request.xhr?
          return render :json => {:success => true, :data =>  {:message => message}}
        else
          respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      else
        message = find_message(:"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" )
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        if request.xhr?
         return render :json => {:success => true, :data =>  {:message => message}}
        else
          respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      messages = resource.errors.messages
      if request.xhr?
       return render :json => {:success => false, :data =>  {:message => messages}}
      else
        respond_with resource
      end
    end
  end

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you want after registration why you are use in sites_controller.rb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doing this to sites_controller.rb will give the current_user.site_id the @site.id that was just made.

```
  def create
    @site = Site.new(site_params)
    @site.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @site.save
        format.html { redirect_to @site, notice: 'Site was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @site }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    if current_user.site_id.blank?
      current_user.site_id = @site.id
      current_user.save
    end 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create it through the [user association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference).

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    if current_user.create_site(site_params)
      format.html { ... }
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

If the site is created as part of the registration, in that you can't create a user without creating their site association, then throw the above line somewhere after the point in your user create method where they're signed in.

If you don't sign in a user after creating them and they have to log in from scratch, put the line in your login method (`UserSession#create` or whatever) after the session is up and `current_user` is available, checking that they don't already have one assigned so you don't clobber their existing site.

Comment: The site ISN'T created as part of registration. Right now, the user must be logged in to create a site. 

So I would put current_user.site_id = @site.id in the Create part in my sessions controller or the sites controller?

Comment: Do it in the sites controller like my first example, then.

Answer (score 0):

When you use has_many and belongs_to rails provide build method for you.

```
 current_user.sites.build(site_params)
```